# Formula for reflection across a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, reflection

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}$I have an equation of a line: $4x - 3y = 0$. Let $S : \Reals^2 \to \Reals^2$ be reflection through that line, and let $P : \Reals^2 \to \Reals^2$ be projection onto that line.

I want to find a vector that represents the reflection through that line and a vector that represents the projection onto that line. Are there any formulas for these?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on this? Something from analytic geometry, say?

Comment: There is no "vector that represents the reflection through that line and a vector that represents the projection onto that line." Those transformations are represented by matrices, not vectors. See my answer to your other, duplicate question. If you don't understand my answer, you should say so there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{u}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\tfrac{3}{5} \\ \tfrac{4}{5}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$
be the unit vector on that line and let $\vec{v}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\tfrac{4}{5} \\ -\tfrac{3}{5}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $\vec{u}$. Any vector
$\vec{a}\in {\mathbb R}^{2}$ and be uniquely repersented as $\vec{a}=\lambda \vec{u}+\mu \vec{v}$ with $\lambda, \mu \in {\mathbb R}$. Then
$$ S\vec{a}=\lambda \vec{u}-\mu \vec{v}\quad \text{and}\quad P\vec{a}=\lambda \vec{u}. $$